# PDF of the Difference of Eigenvalues of a GOE

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

[image: Taken from "Introduction to Random Matrices: Theory and Practice"]

I am trying to arrive at (2.2) in the image attached below (p(s) is the probability density function for s). I tried deriving this by considering how pdfs combine under addition and multiplication but could not arrive at this result. Any hints will help.

Comment: Have you made simulation in order to have an experimental histogram giving an idea of what the pdf should look like ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, no. I am new to RMT so don't know how to do this yet.

Comment: When you write $N(0,1/2)$, do you mean that its variance $\sigma^2=1/2$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, yes.