# Distribution of distance between eigenvalues for GOE when $n=2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, random

This question is a possible duplicate of [PDF of the Difference of Eigenvalues of a GOE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4587690/pdf-of-the-difference-of-eigenvalues-of-a-goe)

I was reading  *Introduction to Random Matrices Theory and Practice* by Giacomo Livan, Marcel Novaes, Pierpaolo Vivo.

[Appetizer: Wigner’s surmise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syUUJ.png)

I don't understand how he reaches 2.2 (in the attached image) by "definition". Could you provide some reference or tell me exactly what definition is he using? Why is $p(s)$ equal to the original joint pdf "tested" against a Dirac Delta?